# Loosing tint in iPad app after splitter popup activated

Tags: ipad, uisplitviewcontroller, tint

I have applied a brown tint to the app. When I select the popup then switch back to landscape view, the app goes back to the default tint. Is there a way to stop that.

here's a few screen shots in order:

1: looks good

[image]

2: Activate popup

[image]

3: Looses tint, reverts to default

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug. I've been following this issue for a very long time. It started out as a problem described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3342596/using-a-tint-on-a-split-view-controllers-master-pane) which apple attempted to fix in iOS 4.2. Unfortunately they didn't fix it properly and now we the behaviour you see above. I reported this to Apple and all I know is that it is a duplicate of bug 8594881. I do not know of any workarounds at this time either.

Comment: Wow ... how is this still happening?  Does anyone know if this is fixed in the iOS 4.3 betas?